# Expand/Collapse specific jpanels

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jpanel

How can I expand or collapse specific [JPanels](https://sites.google.com/site/jqpanel/demo) based on the `Title` or `some id`?

So far I can toggle expand/collapse JPanels using  button.

```
//Assigning a click event on button to trigger expand/collapse JPanel
$('#triggerPanelBtn').click(function(){
    //alert($('.class').children('h3').attr("id"));
    $('.class').children('h3').trigger('click');
});

var panels="";  //Creating JPanels on the fly

var trs='<tr width="100%">'+
    '<th class="thPanel" align="left" width="40%">Database Type</th>'+
    '<td align="left" width="60%" style="word-break:break-all;">Something</td>'+
'</tr>'+
'<tr width="100%">'+
    '<th class="thPanel" align="left" width="40%">Database Version</th>'+
    '<td align="left" width="60%" style="word-break:break-all;">Something</td>'+
'</tr>';

panels+='<div title="Database Version" class="class">'+
    '<div class="jqUIDiv">'+
        '<table class="jpanelTable">'+
            '<tbody>'+trs+'</tbody>'+
        '</table>'+
    '</div>'+
'</div>';

panels+='<div title="ORS Databases" class="class" id="OrsDatabases">'+
    '<div class="jqUIDiv">'+
        '<table class="jpanelTable">'+
            '<tbody>'+trs+'</tbody>'+
        '</table>'+
    '</div>'+
'</div>';

panels+='<div title="Master Database" class="class">'+
    '<div class="jqUIDiv">'+
        '<table class="jpanelTable">'+
            '<tbody>'+trs+'</tbody>'+
        '</table>'+
    '</div>'+
'</div>';

$('#mainContent').empty();
$('<div>')
.html('<div>'+panels)
.appendTo('#mainContent').delay(10).queue(function(){
    $('.class').jPanel({
        'effect'    : 'fade',
        'speed'     : 'slow',
        'easing'    : 'swing'
    });      
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came up with something that helped me

```
$('#triggerPanelBtn').click(function(){
    $('.class').each(function() {  
            if($(this).attr("title")==="ORS Databases")  //I want to Expand/Collapse the JPanel having "ORS Databases" as it's Title
            $(this).children('h3').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the latest jPanel version 1.4 with default open functionality and specify panels to open like below

```
$('#wrapperId').jPanel({
    "defaultOpen"   :  true
            // other settings
});
```

or if you have initialized panels using a class selector and want to open some panels alone using the title from the set on a button click u can do as u mentioned above.